# Hello, could you help me to understand the next error? texmaker (Mac)

Tags: errors, texmaker

This is the error!:

**Overfull \hbox (12.10773pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--19**

*I don´t understand it! 
It has apareces when i try to compilate with the next document:*

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{apacite}

\title{Manual de estrategias psicopedagógicas en el manejo de grupo desde la perspectiva sociocultural}
\author{Itzel Viridiana Gutiérrez Ruiz\\Mayra Yurieth Hernández Robledo}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
%\mainmatter
\include{introduccion}
\backmatter
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Those are warnings, but no errors

Comment: Thanks! but it doesn´t compilate yet and what makes me weird is that in the place where the texmaker identified the warning its from the lines:                                              \date{}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\include{introduccion}

Comment: Strangely enough, when I compile your example, there is no warning at all, let alone an error message... Are you using the latest packages?

Comment: Yesterday it compiled well despite the large title, that was not a problem. I fear the problem is inside the other file you load with `\include`. Perhaps inside there is something wrong that avoid to compile. As @ChristianHupfer says, what you show us is not an error, simply a warning.

Please edit your questions and let us see the content of the file `introduccion` and search the error.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer There are the last packages, we installed MacTeX on a MacBook with MacOS X 10.9, and TeXMaker for write (and Sumblime Text 2 sometimes). Yesterday worked fine.